# Powershell: Find and replace words split by newline

Tags: powershell

So I have a text file that looks something like this:

```
Members : {USER\member1, USER\member2, US
           ER\member3, USER\member4, USER
           \member5, USER\member6}
```

and I would like to remove `USER\`. The following code removes it but not when it's split by a newline, for example when `US` on one line and `ER\` on another line.

```
Foreach-Object { %{$_.Replace('USER\', '') }
```

Putting `` `n or `r `` in there doesn't work. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: why not suppress all linebreaks before running your code ? `%` is an  alias of foreach, why use it twice ??

Comment: You're right that wasn't necessary. I don't know I had that in there.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
PS > ((Get-Content .\t.txt) | % { $_.Trim() }) -join "" -replace "USER\\"
Members : {member1, member2, member3, member4, member5, member6}
```

If the text is in a string-array, switch out `(Get-Content .\t.txt)` with your variable. If you have the text in a string(not array) variable, use:

```
($MYSTRINGVAR.Split("`r`n") | % { $_.Trim() }) -join "" -replace "USER\\"
```

**EDIT** Just modify the "Members" part:

```
$text = (Get-Content .\input.txt) -join "`r`n"
($text | Select-String '(?s)(?<=Members : \{)(.+?)(?=\})' -AllMatches).Matches | % {
        $text = $text.Replace($_.Value, ($_.Value -split "`r`n" | % { $_.Trim() }) -join "" -replace "USER\\")
}
$text | Set-Content output.txt
```

Comment: This works but it changes the format. I'm trying to do it and keep the format as it is, so without trimming any spaces. That's the part I'm struggling with.

Comment: This is because I'm outputting the result into another text file.

Comment: IF "USER\" is the only word with those letters in uppercase(and "\" ), you can use `(Get-Content .\t.txt) -creplace '[USER\\]'` .

Comment: Unfortunately there are other words with those letters in uppercase.

Comment: Is there a way to use your method of trim and join to only apply to the text inside braces '{ ... }'?

Comment: see updated answer for method that only touches the Members-part

Answer (score 0):

There are probably easier ways to get there, but you can give this one a try:

```
$Text = @'
Members : {USER\member1, USER\member2, US
           ER\member3, USER\member4, USER
           \member5, USER\member6}
'@

# First - USER\ with newline inside..
foreach ($index in 1..4) {
    $Text = $Text -replace ('USER\\'.Insert($index,'(\r\n\s+)')), '$1'
}

# Than - pure USER\
$Text = $Text -replace 'USER\\'
$Text
```

As you can see I create few patterns that contain  and keep that element in results (`, '$1'`). For simple ones - I just remove USER\
I've used herestring to create text to work with, it's *possible* that \r may not be needed for actual file.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually just a comment to [Graimer's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14840857/1630171), but it would've been too long and also not readable enough as a comment, so I'm making it a (supplementary) answer instead.

To re-wrap the string after removing `USER\` you could do something like this:

```
$s = "Members : {member1, member2, member3, member4, member5, member6}"

$s -match '^(.*?{)(.*)(})$'
$pad = " " * $matches[1].Length
$matches[1] + ($matches[2] -replace '(.{1,20},) ', "`$1`r`n$pad") + $matches[3]
```

The first regular expression splits the string into 3 parts that can be accessed via the `$matches` collection:

```
Name  Value
----  -----
3     }
2     member1, member2, member3, member4, member5, member6
1     Members : {
0     Members : {member1, member2, member3, member4, member5, member6}
```

`$matches[1]` is the prologue including the opening curly bracket, `$matches[2]` is the member list, and `$matches[3]` is the closing curly bracket. Now you only need to wrap `$matches[2]` at whatever length you want:

```
'(.*{1,20},) '
```

The above means "longest match of at most 20 characters followed by a comma and a space". Replace that with the 1<sup>st</sup> group (`$1`) followed by a line-break (```r``` n``) and a number of spaces that matches the length of the prologue ( ```$pad`) and glue it back together with prologue and trailing curly bracket.

Comment: That's a good idea but there are other things in the file besides the members list. Maybe I'll play around with your idea and see what I can come up with.