# How can I combine multiple groups of lines in a file?

Tags: windows, csv, powershell

I am trying to combine several groups of lines in a file into CSV lines (the groups being separated by one blank line in between each other). I've just copied the lines several times for this example but the information would differ for each group in the actual data files.

```
IM123456
01/20/16 09:44:01 
Reassignment 
PZSR7Z 
Reassignment from xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx to xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx 


IM123456
01/20/16 09:44:01 
Reassignment 
PZSR7Z 
Reassignment from xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx to xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx 


IM123456
01/20/16 09:44:01 
Reassignment 
PZSR7Z 
Reassignment from xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx to xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx 


IM123456
01/20/16 09:44:01 
Reassignment 
PZSR7Z 
Reassignment from xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx to xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx 

IM123456
01/20/16 09:44:01 
Reassignment 
PZSR7Z 
Reassignment from xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx to xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx
```

With the output pasted above, how could I get it to resemble the following?

```
IM123456,01/20/16 09:44:01,Reassignment,PZSR7Z,Reassignment from xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx to xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx 
IM123456,01/20/16 09:44:01,Reassignment,PZSR7Z,Reassignment from xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx to xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx 
IM123456,01/20/16 09:44:01,Reassignment,PZSR7Z,Reassignment from xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx to xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx 
IM123456,01/20/16 09:44:01,Reassignment,PZSR7Z,Reassignment from xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx to xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx 
IM123456,01/20/16 09:44:01,Reassignment,PZSR7Z,Reassignment from xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx to xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx
```

I attempted to utilize the solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14883888/combine-merge-multiple-lines-into-one-line-from-a-text-file-powershell), but I had a difficult time applying it to my example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the file as a whole, split it at 2 or more consecutive line breaks, remove empty elements, then replace the remaining line breaks with commas and write everything back to a file.

```
(Get-Content 'C:\path\to\input.txt' -Raw) -split ' *(\r\n){2,}' |
  Where-Object { $_.Trim() } |
  ForEach-Object { $_ -replace ' *\r\n', ',' } |
  Set-Content 'C:\path\to\output.csv'
```

If your PowerShell version doesn't support `Get-Content -Raw` pipe the `Get-Content` output through `Out-String`:

```
(Get-Content 'C:\path\to\input.txt' | Out-String) ...
```

Comment: awesome, thanks! Going to figure out how that all works

Comment: Or even shorter... `(Get-Content 'C:\path\to\input.txt' -Raw) -split "(?:\r\n){2,}" -replace "\s*\r\n",','`