# Why wont this powershell script execute

Tags: windows, powershell

I'm trying to make a script that does the following:

1. print out a file
2. remove any blank lines
3. filter out all lines that do not contain the word "Reassignment"
4. remove any spaces and ">"'s from the beginning of each line

everything works fine up until I add in the function for step 4, after which powershell spits out a bunch of errors. What am I doing wrong here?

```
PS C:\Users\pzsr7z.000\Desktop\incidentoutput> cat .\csvtest.txt | ? {$_.trim() -ne "" } | sls "^Reassignment$" -Context 1,2 | foreach{ $_.TrimStart(">"," ")}
Method invocation failed because [Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MatchInfo] does not contain a method named 'TrimStart'.
At line:1 char:90
+ ... 1,2 | foreach{ $_.TrimStart(">"," ")}
+                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound

Method invocation failed because [Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MatchInfo] does not contain a method named 'TrimStart'.
At line:1 char:90
+ ... 1,2 | foreach{ $_.TrimStart(">"," ")}
+                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound

Method invocation failed because [Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MatchInfo] does not contain a method named 'TrimStart'.
At line:1 char:90
+ ... 1,2 | foreach{ $_.TrimStart(">"," ")}
+                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound

Method invocation failed because [Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MatchInfo] does not contain a method named 'TrimStart'.
At line:1 char:90
+ ... 1,2 | foreach{ $_.TrimStart(">"," ")}
+                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound
```

All of the functions work on their own individually, things just get screwed up when I try adding on the last part.

Comment: Does not contain... ??? What?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My psychic powers tell me that you're trying to use `String`'s [TrimStart](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trimstart.aspx) method on the [MatchInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.powershell.commands.matchinfo_members.aspx) object returned by [Select-String](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849903.aspx) cmdlet.

Try to cast it to string first:

```
... | sls "^Reassignment$" -Context 1,2 | foreach{ $_.ToString().TrimStart(">"," ")
```

Comment: Hello, when I attempt to use this, the trim function only seems to process the first line of the matched output (see link to screenshot) http://imgur.com/GHggNEs instead of all of the lines. What would cause it to do that?

Comment: @lacrosse1991 Well, I'm not sure why it works at all for you. You're reading content to the array (each line is an element of the array) and then matching each element with `Select-String`. But it means there is no context for `Select-String` to return, because it sees only one line at time. Could you provide an example of your `csvtest.txt` file? Is it the same as in your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35140874/how-can-i-combine-multiple-groups-of-lines-in-a-file)?

Comment: hello, sorry about taking so long to reply. I ended up getting it working although I took a different route. How does this script look to you? I'm brand new to powershell (just started yesterday, have only done perl, bash, and some python before, bash being my favorite) so I would appreciate any opinions you might have. I just took screenshots since pastebin/textsharing sites are blocked on the network.

Script: http://imgur.com/wD2cXxI

Input: http://imgur.com/JNTpSTx (sample of text from a large textfile, I'm processing several files at the same time)

Output: http://imgur.com/C9J4IDl

Comment: @lacrosse1991 There is a dedicated SE site for that kind of questions: http://codereview.stackexchange.com , it'd be much easier to discuss your code there. At quick glance you don't need the temp files and honestly, the solution from your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35140874/how-can-i-combine-multiple-groups-of-lines-in-a-file) should work just fine, you just need to extend it to strip whitespace and `>`. Personally I'd just use [regex](https://regex101.com/r/pW0zZ1/1) (replace `\n` with `\r\n`) to get all data and trimmed it before saving to CSV with `Export-CSV`.

Answer (score 1):

This regex pattern: `^Reassignment$` will only match lines with the *exact* value `Reassignment` - not all lines that *contain* `Reassignment`.

When you're already using `Get-Content` (`cat`) to read the lines from the file, you can as well use the `-match` operator on all the lines (`-cmatch` for case-sensitivity):

```
(cat .\csvtest.txt) -cmatch 'Reassignment'
```

the `-match` operator simply returns the strings that matched, so you can call `TrimStart()` directly on those:

```
$ReassignmentLines = (cat .\csvtest.txt) -cmatch 'Reassignment' |ForEach-Object {
    $_.TrimStart(">"," ")
}
```